# Android Studio: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Today I tried to initialize "ChatSDK" and had a few problems. Now, if I want to start my app it is crashing all time. I found this problem:

```
E/androidRuntime: FATAL EXEPTION: main   Process: com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife, PID: 2605
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.inspredunity.gm.germanminelife-EdgnsjPOMDBCjzzyKZd6KA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
 at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
    at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:727)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:810)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1032)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2345)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5749)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
```

Here are my Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplemenstation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'co.chatsdk.chatsdk:chat-sdk-core:4.4.8'
implementation 'co.chatsdk.chatsdk:chat-sdk-ui:4.4.8'
implementation 'co.chatsdk.chatsdk:chat-sdk-firebase-adapter:4.4.8'
implementation 'co.chatsdk.chatsdk:chat-sdk-firebase-file-storage:4.4.8'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

I tired every fix suggestion which I found at the internet but nothing worked. I hope you guys can help me.
If you need my MainActivity or my gradle file(s) please say it!
Thank you in advance!

***FIXED***

Comment: Have you added `support library` into your the gradle file?

Comment: I am not shure, is it an implementation`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For any person still having this problem after febuary 2019, if you are using androidx or the new material libraries, This problem is happening because Google changed the naming format of the libraries using androidx..  you can check this official mapping https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings 
and search for your library to see what the new name is, now that Google is in androidx

In your case, your library "**android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton**" in your xml file, is now called as using **com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton**

Answer (score 12):

**Android Support Library is no longer maintained.** It is therefore recommended to use [AndroidX Library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) instead.

FloatingActionButton using AndroidX:

**1. Add in gradle:**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

**2. Add in your layout:**

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:src="@drawable/share_button"
    android:layout_margin="16dp" />
```

Comment: And the Google depreciation games goes on. I searched this for an hour, at last not wasted.

Answer (score 2):

Did you add android support library to your project? If not try this one :

```
implementation "com.android.support:design:28.0.0"
```

For more details about how to setup support library, you can check this 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your gradle :

```
implementation com.android.support:design:28.0.0
```